# constant time,linear time complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity

why in the first code time complexity is O(1) and the second code is O(n):

```
//first code:
int i = 0;
while(i < 11)
{
   i=i+1;
}

//second code:
int i =0;
while(i < n)
{
   i = i+1;
}
```

in the second code n is the size.

Comment: Because the first code doesn't depend on any input size.

Comment: I'm sure you would agree that the second one is O(n) and the first one is O(11). Perhaps what you don't know is that O(11) is equal to O(1). See [the Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: @freakish yup i am new to data structure thx bro

Answer (score 1):

> why in the first code time complexity is O(1)

Because it performs a constant number of operations.

> and the second code is O(n)

Because it performs a number of operations that increase linearly in relation to n.

Answer (score 0):

In first code while loop will always run until i reaches 11 so time compexity is O(1).

In second code while loop will run depend on value of n so if you give 11 for n it will run until i reaches 11 but if you give 111 it will run until i reaches 111 so it makes code time complexity O(N) times.